# How to get the selected value of options in php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select option in my php foreach loop,like this below:

```
<td>
   <select  class="select-tlp form-control">
     <option style="display:none;" selected>'.$tlp.'</option>
     <option>RED</option>
     <option>WHITE</option>
     <option>GREEN</option>
   <select>
</td>
```

The problem is that I only need the text of the selected option, but my javascript code is giving me all the select options text.

Javascript:

```
$('select').change(function(){
 var closest = $('select').closest('tr');
 var conceptName = $('.select-tlp',closest).find(":selected").text();
 console.log(conceptName);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you only want to look for the instance specific option

Try

```
$('select').change(function(){
   // "this" is the <select> that was changed
   var conceptName = $(this).find(":selected").text();
   console.log(conceptName);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>
   <select  class="select-tlp form-control">
     <option style="display:none;" selected>pleases select</option>
     <option value="red">RED</option>
     <option value="white">WHITE</option>
     <option value="green">GREEN</option>
   <select>
</td>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('select').change(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());// $(this) -> referrs the 'select' element 
    });
</script>
```